Array modifier along a curve inverted mesh direction
This is my first attempt making any sort of hair, and I would like to propagate it around a curve. However it inverts the intended direction of the hair. Are there any transforms I can apply to fix this?
When I apply the curve, the hair goes inside the head vs normal hair direction.
I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but any guidance would be appreciated.

